# Twitter API rate limit status always shows "remaining" requests as zero

Tags: python, twitter

I'm using `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/followers/list.json?screen_name=user_id&skip_status=true&count=200` to get the list of followers.
After every call of the above API request, I make the following request to check how many requests are still left to avoid "rate limit exceeded" error:

```
rate_limiting = requests.get(url="https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json?resources=followers", auth=oauth).json()
req_left = rate_limiting['resources']['followers']['/followers/list']['remaining']
```

Usually the window to replenish the number of requests to make is 15 mins. But even after waiting for 2 hours, req_left shows me that 0 requests are left.

Is there anything that went wrong with my account? Has Twitter disabled my calls to this API end point?